# Monitors not going into powersave

Tags: xorg, kde, power-management

I have a recent install of F37, which was putting my monitors into power save mode after locking the screen. It recently stopped doing that, but I don’t know when it started.

- Running KDE
- I’ve installed updates and rebooted.
- I’ve created a brand new user, but it still doesn’t go to sleep.

It’s a Dell Optiplex 7040 Micro desktop.

I see this, which looks wrong, but I don’t know if it was happening before, I had no reason to check :)

```
$ xset dpms
server does not have extension for dpms option
```

Random info that could hopefully be useful.

```
$ lsmod | grep i915
i915                 3174400  83
drm_buddy              20480  1 i915
drm_display_helper    180224  1 i915
cec                    81920  2 drm_display_helper,i915
ttm                    94208  1 i915
video                  65536  2 dell_wmi,i915

$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family KT Redirection (rev 31)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 31)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Q170 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM (rev 31)
```

Any direction on how to troubleshoot this would be appreciated.